# react-router: how to get the previous route in onEnter handler?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm trying to find a way to read the previous route/path when a user hits a new one, within the `onEnter` handler.

I have a React Router structured like so:

```
    <Router history={history}>
      <div className="index">
        <Route
          path="/"
          component={ComposedAppComponent}
          onEnter={this.onEnterHandler.bind(this)}
        >
          <Route name="streamKey" path=":streamKey">
            <Route name="articleUri" path="(**)" />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

the function, `onEnterHandler`, looks like so:

```
  onEnterHandler(nextRouteState) {
    const { streamKey, splat } = nextRouteState.params;

    const nextPath = `/${streamKey}/${splat}`;
    const prevPath = // HOW DO I GET THE PREVIOUS PATH?
  }
```

I can't seem to find a way to read the previous route path the user was on... I need to make a comparison between the new route and previous one. Any input on how to approach this is much appreciated. :)

Cheers!

Comment: pretty sure the second argument is the last state.

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback yup

Comment: Oh my mistake, but the function right underneath `onChange` seems to be exactly what you're looking for

Comment: @azium thanks for the tip, but I don't think that will work. I need this to fire when a user enters a route.

Comment: oh... what about just `this` ? I just tried and I get the previous (current) path!

Comment: in case if you use react-router-redux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44288082/3914072

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you trying to get the previous path when the user navigate to new path through address bar or using react-router like `this.context.router.push()`?

If the navigation is using `react-router`, maybe these simple way would get what you're looking for:

**1. Pass `prevPath` using `query-params`**

Navigation might look like this:

```
`<Link to="/next" query={{ prevPath: this.props.location.pathname }}> Your Next path</Link>`
```

Now, you can get your prevPath value on `onEnterHandler` method by using this:
`nextState.location.query.prevPath`

- **Cons**: the query will appear on address bar.
- **Pros**: you are still able to get your `prevPath` when user is navigating through address bar (direct path access).

**2. Pass `prevPath` using state**

Navigation might look like this:

```
`<Link to="/next" state={{ prevPath: this.props.location.pathname }}> Your Next path</Link>`
```

Now, you can get your prevPath value on `onEnterHandler` method by using this:
`nextState.location.state.prevPath`

- **Cons**: the query won't appear on address bar.
- **Pros**: you are not able to get your `prevPath` when user is navigating through address bar (direct path access).

In addition, the cons of those method is you should assign a `prevPath` value into each of Link components. Create a wrapper component for the Link component would solve this issue.

Comment: How would a wrapper around the `Link` component look like? I'm a beginner to React, so I apologize if that is somewhat of a novice question. @mirza.adipradhana

Comment: @JayS. you would create a HOC (higher order component) - lets call it `<MyLink />`. Inside it you'd have a normal `<Link />` however you'd pass it the `query`/`state` prop. Then anytime you use `<MyLink />` instead of `<Link />` you don't need to specify the `query`/`state`, since the wrapper you created will pass it in for you automatically.