# React - how to get the path of last visited page after clicking "previous page" button in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Let's say I'm in Page A(`/path-a`) and I go to page B(`/path-b`).
Afterwards, I click the "previous page" button in the browser.

In this case, how should I get the value of `/path-b` in `PageA.tsx`?

**Update**
I am using `react-router-dom`

Comment: Without knowing which libraries you're using, if any, this question is a bit ambiguous. Are you using react-router-dom, by any chance?

Comment: @Evan Ottinger I am using `react-router-dom`

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming you want a vanilla JS solution:

  You can use `document.referrer`. This will give you the url you come from,
  in the new page.

  For more information you can see this [link](https://codingbeautydev.com/blog/javascript-get-previous-page-url/)
- Assuming you want a React Router Dom solution:

  This [SO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50110622/12570957) from another post explains really well how to do it

Comment: `document.referrer` is empty if after back navigation the page is fetched from the cache.